# Very easy iptables tutorial?

Tags: server, iptables

Where to find a easy "iptables for dummies" tutorial?

I know NOTHING about it and basically I need to allow only http, ssh and ftp connections...

thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a beginner you shouldn't use `iptables` directly, as it probably will give you more problems than it solves. Unless you are familiar with a handful of RFC:s, you should use a frontend instead.

I would really recommend you to use `ufw` if you don't route traffic between different LAN. It's quite easy to use and there are some useful instructions to look up.  But if you do need routing, I have found `shorewall` useful as `ufw` doesn't support any routing or NAT (yet, it's comming). 
The good thing with `ufw` is that it also supports IPv6 besides IPv4, it uses both `iptables` and `ip6tables`.

In short,  use a frontend and not `iptables` unless you really know what you do and you know the differences between different `ICMP` messages.

Answer (score 2):

[This article in the Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) gives a basic rundown of `iptables`. You can also pull up the `man` page for it in Terminal with `man iptables`. Generally, you do not need to use `iptables` for a standard networking configuration, as each service will open the respective ports required for itself. If you have installed Apache, OpenSSH Server and an FTP server like ProFTP, their ports (80, 22 and 21 respectively) will be open.

At the bottom of the article I linked there are instructions for using graphical tools such as GUFW or Firestarter, which may be useful if you don't have a lot of experience working in the command line.

Comment: sorry, i forget to mention that i'm using ubuntu server...

Comment: @Doc No difference - Server and Desktop use the same implementation of `iptables` via `ufw`. If you don't have a GUI on the server, you'll have to use the command line for managing `iptables`.

Comment: @Doc Don't problem, you can use Gufw in Remote Mode. You can run Gufw from other computer (with the operating system you want) and all the settings will be apply to your Ubuntu Server :) +info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw#Use_Gufw_without_Graphical_Environment_or_Remote_Computer

Answer (score 1):

Generally MANuals are the best tutorials for the packages under Linux. However I remember for IPTABLES I also used YouTube videos. I think videos give a better understanding than texts for learning a new concept. Just search IPTABLES in the YouTube and you will see lots of videos. As an example [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PsTYAd6MiI) which I followed myself.